# Index on a table without a where clause

Tags: performance, oracle, indexing

I am trying to select a distinct list of a certain column from a table with many millions of rows, such as:

```
select distinct stylecode from bass.stock_snapshot
```

This query obviously takes a very long time. What performance tuning can I do on this table?
If there are no predicates to my query, will an index help at all?

Comment: An index on stylecode should be usable by the distinct.

Comment: Thanks- just did this on a test table and the explain plan shows it did use the index. Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully it is fast [enough] :)

Comment: setting the column as not null would ensure the best performance also (in the case of that the index is added)

Answer (score 2):

> " just did this on a test table and the explain plan shows it did use
>   the index."

Please bear in mind that you have to maintain that index for ever more.  I don't understand your data but it seems unlikely this index will be useful for other queries, and this query doesn't seem like the sort of query you ought to be running on a frequent basis.

If this is a one-off, some other approach such as parallel query might be better.

If on the other hand it is a frequent requirement perhaps a reference table for STYLECODE would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the concern. This is a legacy system that I am writing ETL extracts from so ongoing maintenance is not a problem.

Comment: _"perhaps a reference table for STYLECODE"_, you mean "add a foreign key to a database" - heretic! :-).